# Rails activerecord joins and duplicates data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, geokit

I'm having a `route` model

```
class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :etapes
  acts_as_mappable :through => :steps
end
```

and a `step` one (that contains lat and lgn)

```
class Step ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :route
  acts_as_mappable
end
```

I'm trying to get the closest `route` to a given point.

With this request `Route.joins(:etapes).within(10, :origin => [1.23456,-5.3269])` I can get the `route`s but I got duplicates informations (because this `route` has many steps closes to the given point):

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [
#<Route id: 1, created_at: "2016-03-26 21:53:01", updated_at: "2016-03-26 21:53:01">, 
#<Route id: 1, created_at: "2016-03-26 21:53:01", updated_at: "2016-03-26 21:53:01">
]>
```

What can I do to remove duplicates entries ?

Comment: `Route.joins(:etapes).within(10, :origin => [1.23456,-5.3269]).uniq` - try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My easy go-to would be

`Route.joins(:etapes).within(10, :origin => [1.23456,-5.3269]).group(:id)`

This generates a `` GROUP BY `routes`.`id` `` which for basic queries will get you what you want. If you need to `COUNT` these, though, then you need to change strategies, since the `COUNT` will apply within-group.

I tend to avoid the `uniq` solution for this purpose as I've found it to perform miserably. Not sure if that generalizes, but it may have to do with it generating a `` SELECT DISTINCT `routes`.* ``, which compares all columns even though you really only need the `DISTINCT` by id.

Comment: Nice one. @AndrewSchwartz If I want to get all routes that match 2 steps, how could I do this ?  I want the result of 

Route.joins(:etapes).within(10, :origin => [1.23456,-5.3269]).group(:id)

and 

Route.joins(:etapes).within(10, :origin => [43.604408, 1.440736]).group(:id)

Comment: I wonder if acts_as_mappable has a solution for this. If not, my instinct would be to go with table aliases, which allow you to join to the same table under two independent conditions. I'd need to know what the `within` method is doing to know how to apply this idea. The general idea is to say `Foo.joins("inner join bars b1 on b1.foo_id = foos.id and <condition for first join> inner join bars b2 on b2.foo_id and <condition for second independent join>")`. It's just not clear to me that you can do this without hacking into the `within` method, though.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to ask them.